# In a topological space $X$, $\overline{A \cap B} \neq \bar{A} \cap \bar{B}$, for all $A, B \subseteq X$. What if $\bar{A} = X$ and $B$ is closed?

Tags: general-topology

In a topological space $X$, $\overline{A \cap B} \subseteq \bar{A} \cap \bar{B}$ but $\overline{A \cap B} \neq \bar{A} \cap \bar{B}$, for all $A, B \subseteq X$. I know the example $A=(0,1)$, $B=(1,2)$ and $X= \mathbb{R}$.

Does the equality hold if $\bar{A} = X$ and $B$ is closed? I know an example in real numbers with the usual topology. The answer is yes if I take $A= \mathbb{Q},~B = [0,1]$ and $X= \mathbb{R}$ but I do not know the answer in general topological space. Thanks . . .

Answer (score 2):

If $A=\mathbb Q$ and $B=\sqrt{2}\ \mathbb Z\ $ and $X=\mathbb R$

Then $\bar A=\mathbb R$ and $B$ is closed since discrete.

$A\cap B=\{0\}$ since $B$ contains only irrationals (plus zero) but $B=\bar A\cap \bar B\neq \overline{A\cap B}=\overline{\{0\}}=\{0\}$

Comment: Thanks you very much ! ! !